# How to randomize and show a small part of the picture?

Tags: html, css

We have this picture

[image: 1]

What I want to try to do is on refresh or on load, the picture highlights a 200x200 square, and removes the rest of the picture like this:

[image: 2] [image: 3]

What is the simplest way to do this without javascript if possible?

Comment: You can place a 200x200 `<div>` container around the image and place it using  `overflow: hidden` on it and `position: absolute`, `top` and `left` on the `<img>` to display the square but you cannot randomly display a different square on reload as nor HTML neither CSS have any RNG included. You'd need either Javascript or a backend language like PHP or Ruby for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do this using CSS and javascript. This will work for any height or width window as it gathers the values from the element.

I've commented the javascript but let me know if you wanted something else.

---

## Demo

```js
// Load image element
image = document.getElementById("random-window-image");

// Get the height and width of the window
window_width =  document.getElementById("random-window-wrapper").offsetWidth;
window_height =  document.getElementById("random-window-wrapper").offsetHeight;

// Calculate a random left value
temp_left = (image.width - window_width) * Math.random();

// Calculate a random top value
temp_top = (image.height - window_height) * Math.random();

// Apply values to the img
image.style.left = "-" + temp_left + "px";
image.style.top = "-" + temp_top + "px";
```

```css
#random-window-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

#random-window-image {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="random-window-wrapper">
  <img id="random-window-image" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Do not answer off topic questions that ask you to write code for them.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(10px,90px,100px,0px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt5HP.jpg" width="200" height="200">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything he asks in his (off topic, should quickly be closed) question. But you shouldn't be answering off topic questions in the first place.